# If $0<a<b$, prove that $a<\sqrt{ab}<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

If $0<a<b$, prove that $a<\sqrt{ab}<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$

So far I've got:

$a<b$

$a^2<ba$

$a<\sqrt{ab}$

And:

$a<b$

$a+b<2b$

$\frac{a+b}{2}<b$

So I need to prove that $\sqrt{ab}<\frac{a+b}{2}$

How can I do it?

Comment: Must you prove this from axioms, or are you allowed to use other theorems? If so, use AM-GM as others have mentioned.

Comment: square both side and move the term and you will have $(a-b)^2>0$ which is obviously true for real number $a<b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to show you, via screenshots (too much effort to try to typeset everything again on here), a chain of inequalities I proved. Your problem is basically the same but even a littler easier.

For my problem, I was given that $a,b\in\mathbb{R^+}$ and $a\leq b$, and I was tasked with proving that
$$
a\leq \frac{2ab}{a+b} \leq\sqrt{ab}\leq\frac{a+b}{2}\leq\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}}\leq b.
$$
Your problem may be easily solved by adapting my work that appears below.

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

If you adapt things correctly, your inequalities will easily fall out.

Comment: That's very bizarre...I am not sure why Inequality 3 shows up twice in the screenshots. Simply disregard the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

That's a private case of AM-GM: $$(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)^2>0\Leftrightarrow a+b-2\sqrt {ab}>0\Leftrightarrow\frac{a+b}{2}>\sqrt{ab}$$

Answer (score 2):

The last part of your proof is precisely the Arithmetic Mean - Geometric Mean (AM-GM) inequality.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
Use the AM-GM inequality.