# Show 3 propositions are equivalent by proving a given set of implications

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I am giving the following propositions:

$p: a < b$

$q: \frac{a+b}{2} > a$

$r: \frac{a+b}{2} < b$

$a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

I need to show that these are equivalent by proving the following:

$(p \implies q) \land (q \implies r) \land (r \implies p)$

So they are all strong together by the **and** I assume I should prove each of these implications separately and then show that the conclusions are all equivalent. I don't want the whole question solved for me, but I am looking for a base.

If I look at $p \implies q$, where would I start here? Should I be using a direct proof, contraposition, or a contradiction to best solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll outline a much more efficient way to structure your proof.

Suppose $a<b$. Then $2a=a+a<a+b<b+b=2b$. Since $2=1+1>0$, we have that $2^{-1}>0$, so that $a<(a+b)\cdot 2^{-1} < b$, which we may write as $a<\frac{a+b}{2}<b$, as desired.

---

If you absolutely *must* do all of the proofs by implication (really unnecessary and inefficient), then here is how you may do the first one (I trust you can do the rest):
\begin{align}
a < b &\Rightarrow a+a < a+b\\[0.5em]
      &\Rightarrow a < \frac{a+b}{2}.
\end{align}
The other two implications may be shown similarly, but for the inequality you want to prove...this line of attack seems like a waste of time.

Comment: Well I don't know if I necessarily need to do this by implication. The question does not specify. However I am pretty new to this, and doing it via implication just seemed like the easier way to do it for me, as the other way seems more complex than I fully understand.

Comment: @Fogest Ah. Then *definitely* use the approach I first gave. Your approach is a major pain in the butt. The only time you would use a series of implications like what you're attempting to do would be to prove a series or chain of inequalities where proving the implications actually saves some work. For example, check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1114615/if-0ab-prove-that-a-sqrtab-fracab2b/1114633#1114633) answer I gave which makes use of your line of reasoning. That was necessary there because of how many inequalities there were. Yours is small though :)

Comment: Why is $a+a < a+b$ in this? (regarding the implication)

Comment: I would love to use your first approach, but I do not fully understand it, so trying to use it as an answer isn't going to work out well as I won't be able to put it down on paper in a way that makes sense.

Comment: @Fogest Why does $a<b$ imply $a+a<a+b$? Well, consider something concrete: $2<3$; thus, $2+2<2+3$.

Comment: Okay ,that makes sense, thanks! Would I apply the same concepts to the other two implications, or do I need to use different reasoning?

Comment: @Fogest Yes, you can use the same reasoning. Honestly, I would consult my teacher about these things. He/she may be able to clarify some things more easily than I can by being in person.

Answer (score 2):

Use a direct proof for each. Remember you can add or subtract the same thing to both sides of an inequality, or multiply or divide by a positive constant, and the inequality is preserved.